# to dispaly alerts whenever the input fields are empty and show the eror message while clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, html, css

When the mobile no field is left empty the alert should appear while clicking on the submit button. Enter password and confirm password to show error while password mismatch. How to add the alerts?
Here is the registration form code:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h2>Login</h2>
<form>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="mobile number">mobile no:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter mobile number">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="reenter  password">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="pwd">firstname:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="enter first name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="pwd">last name::</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="enter last name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="pwd">select city:</label>

<select name="select city" ><option>mangalore</option><option> mysore</option><option>hubli</option><option>dharvad</option></select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="pwd">select state:</label>
<select name="select state" placeholder="state"> <option>kerala</option>  <option>karnataka</option><option>tamil nadu</option></select>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there are jquery form validation scripts you can use

Comment: Please clean up your question. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, we all take our time (which some people would pay for) to help each other out. The least you can do is make your question easier to answer by using normal english and capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using modern browsers supporting html5 then a "required" attribute might be useful too. It is simpler method.